# Are Helheim and the Halls of Valor actually realms in The Shadowlands?

Tags: warcraft

The current expansion (Shadowlands) for World of WarCraft has introduced players to six of the realms in The Shadowlands, which is the afterlife that most souls go to once a being dies. There are exceptions to this rule, such as elementals (which re-form in their elemental plane), void-lords (which re-form in the Void), etc. We've seen physical, mortal beings who go to other places upon death, though:

- Vrykul go to either the Halls of Valor or Helheim
- Wild Gods, dragons, and druids go to the Emerald Dream
- Naaru go to some sort of Light-based afterlife we haven't seen yet

Given that the plane of The Shadowlands is said to have countless realms in addition to the ones we can play in, it makes me wonder if all these areas might not be connected. I play the game, but don't generally read the novels or comics. I'm hoping, however, that this question has been addressed somewhere in all that lore.

**Is there any indication that these various realms - specifically, Halls of Valor, Helheim, and the Emerald Dream - are actually realms inside The Shadowlands?**

Comment: There seems to be a lot about this in the Chronicles: Volume 1 book - *"*Helya, now liberated from her life of servitude, forged a new home for herself and the other Val’kyr. She created this enchanted refuge far below the Halls of Valor, binding it to Azeroth’s great seas. The ocean mists soon coiled up to envelop Helya’s domain and shroud it from sight. Known as Helheim, this realm would become the final destination for many vrykul spirits after death.*"

Comment: "*Helya wove a great spell to encase the keeper’s stronghold. Then, focusing all of her power, she ripped the colossal chunk of Ulduar from the earth and lifted it into the cloudy skies. In time, this floating citadel would become known as the Halls of Valor.*"

Comment: "*THE EMERALD DREAM - The Emerald Dream is an ethereal realm of spirits and untamed nature that exists alongside the world of Azeroth.*"

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means, having never play the game or read any of the books.

Comment: @Valorum - sounds like they're considered separate from The Shadowlands, then. If you want to put those quotes in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. BTW, you're probably missing out - WarCraft has a pretty rich lore behind it... at times, it's almost as intricate as The Elder Scrolls franchise (not quite as great, but still very good). Unfortunately, it's been on a steady decline lately - the last couple of expansions haven't added much to it.